# How to fade in/out your background in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new in three.js and I am still learning. I have three buttons for different backgrounds, but when I click it I want to fade in and out.

I am using this code for my buttons.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'pic.jpg' )
} );

var backgroundButton = document.getElementById('change-background-1');
backgroundButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
   material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('pic.jpg');
});

var backgroundButton = document.getElementById('change-background-2');
backgroundButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
   material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('pic1.jpg');
});

var backgroundButton = document.getElementById('change-background-3');
backgroundButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
   material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('pic2.jpg');
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the opacity value of the material.

Have a look:
http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Materials/Material

`mesh.material.opacity = 1;`

Simplest way is maybe use a tweening engine (example: [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/gsap)).

Example:

`mesh.material.opacity = 0;
TweenMax.to(mesh.material, 1, { opacity: 1 });`

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your materials over time on **2 points** :

- set `mesh.material.transparent = true`
- then dynamically 'lerp' opacity between 0 and 1 : `mesh.material.opacity = opacityOverTime`